# Does ${\bf CPO}$ have $\omega$-colimits?

Tags: category-theory

Does the category ${\bf CPO}$ have $\omega$-colimits? By ${\bf CPO}$ I mean the category that has as objects the $\omega$-complete pointed partial orders and as arrows $\omega$-continuous functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Consider the $\omega$-diagram $D=(\{0\}\to \{-1,0\}\to \{-2,-1,0\}\to\cdots)$ in $\mathbf{CPO}.$ Suppose $X$ were the colimit of our diagram and let $Z=\{-\infty_1,-\infty_2,\ldots,-2,-1,0\},$ where $-\infty_1<-\infty_2$ and both $-\infty_i$ are strictly smaller than every integer in $Z.$ Then there should be a unique map $X\to Z$ consistent with the inclusions of the $\{-i,\ldots,0\}.$ This implies all the maps $\{-i,\ldots,0\}\to X$ are injective, since the corresponding maps to $Z$ are, and by the cocone property, $X$ has a sub-poset isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{\le 0}=\{\ldots,-2,-1,0\}.$ Since $\mathbb Z_{\le 0}$ is not pointed (contains no $\perp$), $X$ must contain at least one further, distinct element $\perp$ below all of these.

Now any map $f:X\to Z$ consistent with the cocone maps must send $\perp$ to either $-\infty_1$ or $-\infty_2$ in order to be monotone. This produces a contradiction, since $Z$ has an endomorphism sending both $-\infty_i$ to $-\infty_2$ as well as one sending both $-\infty_i$ to $-\infty_1,$ composing with one of which changes $f$ while preserving its respect for the cocones.

Abstractly, the problem with $\mathbf{CPO}$ is the requirement that bottom elements exist, but not be preserved by the morphisms. If you looked at just $\omega$-complete posets, or required morphisms to preserve the bottom elements, then you would have categories that are cocomplete, and indeed, accessibly monadic over posets.

Comment: Do you have an intuition for why it has been chosen to allow morphisms in CPO that re not preserving the bottom element? If with this additional restriction the category is better-behaved, what is there to gain with the more general notion of morphisms?

Comment: Why should there be a morphism $X\to Z$ if $Z$ is not in CPO ($Z$ lacks a bottom element but is countable, so is not $\omega$-complete)?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Thanks, I have modified $Z$ to have a bottom element. I think we're working from different definitions, even so: I have that an $\omega$-complete poset has a least upper bound for every countable chain. This doesn't imply the existence of a bottom element since the chain can't be empty. It's the *pointed* part of the terminology that seems to require the bottom element. (Caveat that I'm a category theorist, not a domain theorist, so I could be missing something.)

Comment: @fosco This is apparently an important category in domain theory a la Dana Scott. I don't really know anything about this but a pointed complete poset is supposed to represent something like a type for a programming language whose terms are allowed to be only partly specified (Maybe computable real numbers are a good example to have in mind?); then if $x< y,$ the semantic is supposed to be that $y$ is consistent with but more fully specified than $x.$  Con't...

Comment: Then $\perp$ represents a totally unspecified piece of data. (Like something that's been initialized and no more?)  Continuous functions are supposed to represent computations, but computations need to be able to refine fully unspecified data, so you don't want to require $f(\perp)=\perp.$ It's a pretty interesting example to have arise naturally; I'm not sure anything very similar comes to mind within pure math.